# Can users in one domain be assigned to Groups in another domain if both domains are in the same Forest?

Tags: active-directory

Say there is a domain A with users in DCa. And there is another domain B with groups in DCb. But both DCa and DCb are in the forest F. Is it possible to assign users in domain A to be assigned in to groups in domain B ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no.

You can assign the users in one domain to the *Universal Group* or *Domain Local Group* in another domain within the same forest.

You cannot assign users in one domain to the *Global Group* in another domain within the same forest.

Check [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755692%28WS.10%29.aspx) for more details